# Chat prompts me to act on flagged messages, but there are no flagged messages to display

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Recently I gained over 10,000 reputation network-wide. However, now when I am in [The Comms Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) I receive a notification that there are flags to act on, but when I click on it, there are no flagged messages.

To be clear, I have had over 10,000 network-wide reputation for at least a couple of weeks, and yet I have not seen this particular notification until today.

[image]

1. Gain 10,000 reputation network-wide.
2. Enter chat and wait for a message to be flagged.

Expected behavior:

- When notification of flagged messages appears, flags to be acted on exist. The notification can be removed by clicking on it.

Actual behavior:

- When notification of flagged messages appears, there are no flags to display. Clicking on the notification does not remove it.

Comment: The fact that you get notifications is expected, just not that the circle refuses to go away even though there's nothing left to act on.

Comment: It only went away for me after a refresh

Comment: There have been several reports of this, so this is very likely a bug.

Comment: It continues to be an issue even after I've exceeded 10K rep again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The 10k threshold that's relevant here is the network-wide combined rep, so I wouldn't have expected any difference there.

Comment: Indeed. I've cut down the question and steps to reproduce based on my greater understanding of the issue.

Comment: @balpha, out of interest what happens when the network gets to 97 sites and someone can get 10k rep network wide by getting 200 on one site and then going and getting the association bonus on all the others?

Comment: @Ben You can actually fulfill the 20 rep requirement for chat by just registering on 20 sites (at least for chat.se). That's a known loophole (and similar to what you describe). We'll close that eventually, but it hasn't turned into a real problem yet.

Comment: I was under the impression that this was due to flags being cleared before you saw that...maybe not after all.

Comment: It still happens. I've encountered it twice. It is possible that this only occurs when the chat window is blurred.

Comment: @balpha: This is not fixed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Please don't revive age-old bug reports like this one that were (once) fixed. Open a new one instead with current details.

Comment: @balpha: Okay but it'll be an exact dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found (and fixed) one issue that does indeed cause this. Since this issue should be rare, and given the amount of people who have reported this, I'm not totally convinced that this was the *only* issue. Hence I'm not calling this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) yet; I'll be watching it for a while.

Please let me know if you see this again (or don't see it again for a long time).

Note that your "expected behavior" is not at all expected – if a new message is flagged, you should very well get a notification of this.

**Update.** As several people (including myself) noticed, this indeed was *not* the main issue. As always, the problem was with cachingand timing. The flag count that's displayed to you is cached on the server side, and this cache is only cleared when a new flag-relevant event happens. When your chat client receives a flag event, it queries the server for an updated flag count to display to you.

However, since you received the flag event from the websocket server (this issue wouldn't have appeared for users without websocket-supporting browsers), but get the flag count from the regular webserver, it can happen that the latter hasn't processed the new flag event yet and thus hasn't updated the cache yet, while the former is already happily handing the event out to clients.

This is fixed now. This involves changes both on the server and on the client, so for the full benefit, you'll have to refresh your JavaScript (but even with the old JS, it should be less likely to happen now).

Comment: Just happened, so it's not fixed.

Comment: Happened to me aswell just minutes ago

Comment: In case it helps, I dismissed the flag as valid and the flag count *increased* to 2; not sure if it was coincidental timing or part of the/a bug. And I've still got the bubble over 5 minutes later.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually seen it myself today. So this definitely wasn't the only issue.

Comment: Also, why were you posting this 12 hours ago? I know SE means a lot to a lot of people, but pushing fixes at 4am?

Comment: @Kevin Check my profile for my location :)

Comment: @balpha ok, 10:30pm is better, but that's still some dedication.

Comment: @Kevin Now you have to check your date math.

Comment: Oops, I'm seeing it again this afternoon. I also updated the question; hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Seeing it again. Persists across refresh (must be cookie related?) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11971780#11971780

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the chat flags because you have over 10k reputation network wide. When you click on the flag and find nothing there, this is most likely because someone else already handled. All moderators in chat rooms and non mods with suitable privileges get poked by the chat flags so they generally get handled fairly quickly.

Comment: OK, then the problem is it doesn't go away. :)

Comment: It happened to me too. (It doesn't go away.)

Comment: I should also note that I've had over 10K network wide for some time now, and this is the first time I've seen this notification or the chat flagging system _at all_.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you mean the badge showing the flag count doesn't go away?

Comment: @kiamlaluno The badge showing the flag count does not go away when clicked on.