# Chat Flag Bubble doesn't clear after action

Tags: bug, chat, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chat prompts me to act on flagged messages, but there are no flagged messages to display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147211/chat-prompts-me-to-act-on-flagged-messages-but-there-are-no-flagged-messages-to)

As a 10k+ user, I am notified of any spam/offensive flags in chat. I am given the option of agreeing with, disagreeing with, or ignoring the flag.

After choosing an action, the flag is no longer in my queue of flags, and the blue bubble on my gravatar should disappear.

The problem is the blue bubble isn't getting cleared, and sticks around indefinitely, until I refresh the page. This also occurs if a flag is raised while AFK, and the flag is resolved before I return.

Comment: I am also experiencing this.

Comment: This affects me too.

Comment: There have been several reports of this, so this is very likely a bug.