# Remove flag indicator if no flags exist

Tags: bug, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chat prompts me to act on flagged messages, but there are no flagged messages to display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147211/chat-prompts-me-to-act-on-flagged-messages-but-there-are-no-flagged-messages-to)

Every once in a while I see this little, blue guy in chat: [image]

I usually click on it and get greeted with:

[image]

I can then close that window, but the blue indicator will remain, waiting for me to repeat the pattern.

Comment: I think there are a lot of places where this kind of thing can happen. My inbox notification has a red 1 (and a link to the comment) even if the comment has long been deleted.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147211/chat-prompts-me-to-act-on-flagged-messages-but-there-are-no-flagged-messages-to

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yeah, but that one disappears when I click on it. The one in chat stays until you refresh.

Comment: This has been reproing on SO for quite a while now. Virtually every morning I wake up to a ghost bubble.