# Flag indicator in chat season 3 episode 10

Tags: bug, flags, chat

I know this might be a dupe of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147211/chat-prompts-me-to-act-on-flagged-messages-but-there-are-no-flagged-messages-to) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148161/remove-flag-indicator-if-no-flags-exist) or maybe [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189159/flag-number-not-disappearing) and I am sure there will be others to find, but this issue still is not resolved (and those posts are either old or [status-i-hope-i-fixed-it-now](/questions/tagged/status-i-hope-i-fixed-it-now)). Or maybe it was resolved but someone ([not pointing fingers here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha)) has broken it again. Again I am not here to [blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/96/) anyone.

I just want to point out that the issue still is present in chat and it is a pretty annoying issue (yes I am annoyed fast).

The problem is that sometimes the flag badge in chat gets "stuck". Meaning it will tell you (in a very convincing tone) that there is some flag to handle, but when clicking it you will be greeted by the message there aren't any flags to handle.

It has been like this for a while so I cannot really tell when it started doing this.

Comment: Juicy! Can't wait for episode 11!

Comment: @animuson I hear that season 4 will be amazing