# New messages flagged blue bubble does not go away

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, chat

When someone flags a message in chat all 10k+ users in chat get a little blue bubble to vote on. It shows up in the upper left hand corner of your gravatar (which is in the bottom left of the page).

When someone flags a message and it shows up, if I wait for a second to click on it, and then click on it, and it has already been handled, it shows the message

"There are no flags to display."

In the past, after showing this message, the blue (1) would disappear. However, lately it has not been going away and requires a page refresh in order to remove. Can this be fixed?

This issue is addressed here: [Chat prompts me to act on flagged messages, but there are no flagged messages to display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147211/178816) from September 12th 2012. But since it is still occurring 10 months later, I believe the cause is different.

[image: Image to illustrate]

Comment: I have noticed this too. I'm running Opera.

Comment: I have observed this using chrome v28

Comment: I still see this rarely, though not often enough to bother re-posting.

Comment: I suppose you mean top left, or your image is from something else

Comment: @fotanus - Both are correct. But just to clarify, The gravatar is at the bottom left of the page. The blue circle is in the top left of the gravatar. I also made an edit to the question so there was no confusion.

Comment: Happens on Safari too.

Comment: Just like to add - the blue bubble sticks for way too long after there are no flags.

Comment: I like the bounty text.

Comment: @PeeHaa What what what what what why me?

Comment: I'm tempted to set up some sock-puppet accounts just to up-vote this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently [I was chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymcph.png) to fix this :)

At some point an optimization was made to the chat event processing that broke cache invalidation for the flag counts, and unfortunately this breakage has a pretty good chance to only appear in production.

I've made two changes:

- I've "worked around" this optimization to ensure the flag count cache is invalidated as appropriate.
- When you click the blue (1) and the server says there are no flags, we now just remove the blue bubble. So even in the case that an incorrect number is cached, you only have to click *once*, and then the bubble is gone. I've resisted this change so far because it really hides potential bugs, but there's a point to be made for not annoying users.

Both changes are deployed (the second one needs a JavaScript update).

Comment: All this for meager 50 rep? I had high hopes for you! :D

Comment: thaaaaaanks @balpha!