# Chat flag notification, but no flag

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, chat-flags

It appears [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147211/307833) is back. Upon refreshing any chat page (even when dumping the cache and hard reloading), a chat flag notification is displayed, but there is no chat flag.

[image: notification]

[image: no flags]

Comment: For [me too.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34831327#34831327) And [@ThomasWard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34831364#34831364).

Comment: I flagged something and it stopped showing up with the ghosts...

Comment: This has happened to me at least twice as well.

Comment: [And now as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSLBn.png).