# Chat flag counter on "Main" Chat.SE appears to be stuck

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface

There appears to be a stuck chat flag counter

To replicate: As a moderator go to chat.se, and you see a chat flag counter. Click on it and there aren't any flags, and it vanishes. Refresh or go to another chatroom and the flags come back.

I've added a GIF image of the issue to demonstrate:

[image: animated gif of stuck chat flag counter]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289916/chat-flag-notification-but-no-flag similar bug, from years ago. While the details might be the same, I think enough time as past not to be a dupe

Comment: While I did see a stuck flag counter in each room on chat.SE I was in, once I cleared all of the counters in every room which I had open in a tab, the counter did not return when I reloaded all of those tabs. I did not try reloading the tabs prior to clearing all the flag counters.

Comment: I tried leaving every room but TL, and I didn't manage to dismiss it

Comment: Happens to me (as a non-moderator) as well.

Comment: Happens always, just takes some time to clear, probably hour or so. During this hour the counter is immortal and will always show, at least for me. I learned to just ignore it.

Comment: Its been like that all day

Comment: Happens to me as well, and it's especially annoying since I'm one of those people who things chat moderation shouldn't be forced onto people just because they're past the "we're actively hostile to new users" stage...

Comment: Appears to be OK now.

Comment: It went away after I rebooted - but I'm not sure if the issue is sorted or not, or its transient.